# Android build not generating, after submitting iOS app to AppStore : Is there limit for phonegap build compilation?

Tags: android, ios, cordova

I already submitted iOS app to AppStore which is developed by using Phonegap Build. After that when I went to compile Android app version from Phonegap build, it is not completing [as we can see screen shot] For your information, both Android and iOS version app has got same package name. The zip file uploaded completely, and clicked on "*Ready to build*" button. The build is not generating/completing even after 15min.! as you can see in below screen shot.

[image]

Any quick solution ?

/***** UPDATE ******/

Now  I am able to compile build through friend's github account, but not with mine! IS **THERE ANY NUMBER LIMIT FOR THE BUILD COMPILATION IN PHONEGAP BUILD** ??

Thanks and Regards,

Comment: Do you get any error message?

Comment: No dude. No error message on compiling.

Answer (score 0):

iOS submission to AppStore has nothing to do with the Android build. 
As I can see you are using PhoneGap. 
Is the iOS version building and the Android not building?

Comment: This should be a comment and not an answer.

Comment: I am not able to give comments to other Answers than mine, because I have less than 50 reputation.

Comment: I am using phonegap build.

Comment: Hey,I am able to build with my friend's github account, not with mine!!

Comment: I don't know anything about a 100 times limit.